# Поведение финальных полей java

Tags: java

Допустим есть класс A с финальными полями

```
public class A {
    protected final int a;

    protected final int  b;

    public A() {
        Random random = new Random();
        a = random.nextInt();
        b = random.nextInt();


    }
}
```

Класс B наследник A

```
public class B extends A {


}
```

main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(a.a);
        System.out.println(a.b);
        System.out.println(b.a);
        System.out.println(b.b);

    }
}

Output:

1290498689
937636620
1338493434
-2021025263
```

Т.е. поля  меняются, не пойму  почему??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу вы путаете логику работы модификаторов `static` и `final`.

1. Модификатор `final` служит для создания константы
2. Модификатор `static` служит для обращения к членам класса без создания экземпляра класса (т.е. они являются общими для всего класса)

---

Мне кажется, что вы получите ожидаемое поведение, если напишете так:

```
class A
{
    protected static final int a = new Random().nextInt();
    protected static final int b = new Random().nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Если класс А переписать  так 
class A 
{
Randon ranodom = new Random();
protected final a = random.nextInt();
protected final b = randon.nextInt();

} 
поведение не меняется

Comment: @ketchyn дак вы куда модификатор `static`-то дели? (присмотритесь к тому, как я написал в примере: `static final`)

Comment: да так работает, но мне нужно что бы поля инициализировались  из конструктора и только 1 раз

Comment: @ketchyn Окей, тогда объявите поля `a` и `b` вот так: `protected static int a;` (т.е. без `final`) и присвойте им значения в конструкторе класса `A`.

Comment: хм. да пожалуй так пойдет спасибо

Answer (score 12):

Какие поля?

У вас:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

`a` и `b` два разных объекта, логично, что их поля различаются.

Comment: если у них разные поля почему в классе B в конструкторе запись a=3 компилятор ругается.

Comment: Потому что `a` задаётся в родительском конструкторе.

Comment: @ketchyn Вы поймите, что ваши поля `a` и `b` являются как бы константами, т.е. их можно проинициализировать лишь 1 раз, а как уже сказал @Suvitruf, эта инициализация происходит в конструкторе класса `A`, а т.к. конструктор класса `B` неявно вызывает `super()`, тем самым вызывая конструктор родительского класса `A` без параметров, то и при коде `B b = new B()` такое и происходит.

Comment: ну так правильно  1) создаю объект  класса A -инициализируетються поля 1 раз по вашей логике, создаю обьетк клааса B-должны быть те же значения полей, но они другие,

Comment: @ketchyn Хм, давайте так (пример из реальной жизни): представьте, что у вас есть машины `A` и `B` и у них есть детали `a` и `b` (детали схожие, но у каждой свои, например, `a` = руль, `b` = двигатель), когда собирали (_инициализировали_) машину `А`, то ей усановили _руль_ и _двигатель_, а при сборке машине `B` тоже установили идентичные _руль_ и _двигатель_ (идентичные, но на самом деле это 2 разных _руля_ и _двигателя_!)

Comment: я понимаю что тут 1 из 2 вариантов либо переменные 1 и теже либо у каждого разные но одинаковые, Все разобрался-  мне было непонятно почему нельзя в классе А в конструкторе написать а=3 если поля разные, нельзя  т.к. он вызывает конструктор суперкласса, можно так this.a=3. О чем вы в принципе написали,но до меня не дошло с первого раза)

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется у вас неправильные представления о работе наследования. Когда вызывается конструктор класса B, то выполняется код написанный в конструкторе класса А, но для полей объекта B. Объект A имеет свои поля `a, b`, которые никак не связанны с полями объекта В.

```
public class A {
    protected int a;
    protected int b;

    public A() {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        a = 3;
        b = 4;
    }
}
```

После создания объектов классов A и B:

```
a.a равно 1
a.b равно 2
b.a равно 3
b.b равно 4
```

---

Пример с final полем:

```
public class A {
    protected final Integer a;

    public A() {
        a = new Integer(1);
    }
}

public class B extends A {  }
```

---

```
System.out.println(a.a == b.a); // т.к. поле а у нас ссылочного типа, а не примитивного (мы объявили его как Integer()), здесь мы проверяем равны ли ссылки на поля
```

Результат будет: `false`
У нас будут содержаться одинаковые значения поля `a` в обоих объектах, но сами поля будут разные.

Comment: В вашем примере в классе B компилятор подчеркнет такую инициализацию  с подписью "can not asign final variable a" - значит использует те же поля

Comment: @ketchyn, нет, не подчеркнет. Обратите внимание, что я использовал поля без модификатора final.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, добавив пример с final.